# How to prevent spark parquet scan on every query

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks, delta-lake

I created a delta lake table in databricks using a SQL command like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
USING DELTA
LOCATION '/mnt/s3-mount-point/mytable/'
AS
SELECT
  A,
  B,
  C
FROM t1
```

I then optimized the table:

```
OPTIMIZE mytable
ZORDER BY (A)
```

When I query the table using a simple query like below, spark fires off 26,537 ScanParquet tasks. The table that I'm working with is on the order of 3.5 TB stored in 9,000 files. The cardinality of A is greater than 2 million

```
SELECT
  A,
  B,
  C
FROM mytable
WHERE A = 'value'
```

A few questions:

1. Why are the number of tasks to scan this table significantly greater than the number of files?
2. Why is every file being scanned if the table is zordered for this column? Shouldn't the data for 'value' be colocated in the same file? In this case, rows with 'value' represent roughly 5E-7 of the whole data, so it should be located in the same parquet file.
3. Why is the entire table scanned again when I perform the same query? This is true if I cache the table in 'Delta Cache' or not. I can't cache in memory since it would far overwhelm the memory available to the workers.

Answer (score 1):

1. The files are optimized to ~1gb (most likely).  Spark splits the files in 128mb chunks, for the read.
2. If youre using databricks, I dont expect the entire
   table to be scanned.  You can validate its not reading all the files
   by looking at the spark ui, then going to the sql tab and looking at
   number of files in the read stage.
3. Lazy evaluation re-runs the dag.  If your using a delta cache enabled instance, it should read from cache on 2nd read.  Check the spark ui, the go to the sql tab and see the cache read metrics.

If youre seeing something that contradicts what I said, let me know, and I'd like to explore further.